# What steps can I take to ensure that my rails app on heroku isn't effected by another ec2 outage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, heroku, redundancy

My app is a victim of the recent EC2 outage and is still offline. The outage has negatively effected my business and the relationship we have with our clients. I'm hosting the app on heroku with their shared database plan. If a similar outage were to happen again, what can I do to ensure that my app isn't effected? I would like to keep it on heroku if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku depends on Amazon EC2, so if EC2 is down, then Heroku is down.  Heroku and EC2 are still pretty reliable in general though, and every service provider can have problems from time to time.

I'd say that if you want to stay on Heroku, there's probably not much you can do to reduce your risk.  You might be able to do better by hosting with someone that has a stronger service level agreement than Heroku.  Just one example: http://www.rackspace.com/whyrackspace/network/index.php.

Comment: Also, I think Amazon will likely have a lot of explaining to do, due to the extended outage. I realize that your customers probably don't care - they only care if your app is up or not. For a lot of people, this is definitely one of those times they are questioning the value that Amazon is providing. Steve is completely right, that reliability is still very high, and that these kinds of outages very rarely happen. That doesn't fix the customer's perception, nor does it help your reputation with your customers. :(